# 3 questions, each relevant ... is it possible to loop function declarations, call system objects, and load assemblies from strings?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have some ideas that I think are pretty cool, but I don't know how to get it all to work... So, i'll ask away...

I have a question, and they're all pretty similar, so I have a feeling that they may all have the same answer, I'm not sure though.

I've tried using TypeDefinitions , Add-Type , New-Object , etc. but none of these things work. I've been messing around with the math involved... and despite my best efforts? Still haven't figured out how to get it to work. I've asked fellow programmers, but they may all have the wrong idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. So here goes...

````
# Being able to call system objects, or system type objects from an array of common strings ( lets call each one it's own 'lego' ). #
# Instead of ... #
if ([ Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal ][ Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([ Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole ]'Administrator')
{ execute the script... }

# You could do this...
$0 = "." , "Windows" , "Security" , "Principal" , "Identity" , "BuiltInRole"
$1 = -join $0[ 2 , 0 , 3 , 0 , 1 ]
$2 = $0[ 3..5 ] | % { New-Object $1 + $_ }
if (-join $2[0..1]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole($2[2])
{ execute script }
# Haven't gotten it working yet though, can't really call methods or types from a string as far as I know, but I know that SID strings are essentially calling types from a numerical index hence "S-1-5-21-...etc"


```

# Calling assemblies or assembly types from an array of strings (in the same manner as above for loading ASP.Net Assemblies - which are also system objects
# Example of how they're loaded now....
using System ;
using System.Collections.Generic ;
using System.Diagnostics ;
using System.Linq ;
using System.Threading.Tasks ;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc ;
using securedigitsplus.Models ;

# and how I'd like to load them in PowerShell and not even need the .cs files
$0 = "System" , ".Collections.Generic" ,  ".Diagnostics" , ".Linq" , ".Threading.Tasks" , "#etc.....#"
$1 = $0[0] , @( foreach ( $j in 1..4 ) | % { -join $0[0,$j] } )
0..$1.count | % { using ( New-Object or Add-Type -TypeDeclaration $_ I've tried both with no success... }

```

# Lastly... an example of redundant similar Function calls

Function Log-Message ( $MSG ) { $MSG | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force }
Function Log-Console ( $MSG ) { Write-Host $MSG -F White  ; Log $MSG }
Function Log-Warning ( $MSG ) { Write-Host $MSG -F Yellow ; Log $MSG }
Function Log-Success ( $MSG ) { Write-Host $MSG -F Green  ; Log $MSG }
Function Log-Error   ( $MSG ) { Write-Host $MSG -F Red    ; Log $MSG }

# The idea to make it less redundant, create the same number of functions by looping the function declarations

$f = "Console" , "Warning" , "Success" , "Error"
$m = "White" , "Yellow" , "Green" , "Red"
0..4 | % `
{
    if ( $_ -eq 0 ) 
    {  
        Function Log { $MSG | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force }
    }

    else
    { 
        Function "$( $f[$_] )" # I was thinking maybe Set-Variable ?
        {
            Write-Host $MSG -F $m[$_] ; Log $MSG
        }
    }
 }
````

I hope that I've given a good enough explanation or examples of what I'm trying to do. The general idea is that I'd like to be able to create CmdLetBinding() in a loop at some point, especially if there are a bunch of similar ones and DefaultParameterSetName doesn't seem to be as good of a solution, but I'm only looking to do this with simple functions / switches for now.

If anyone is thinking it "you're trying to reinvent the wheel here"... I guess there's some merit to that... but the way I see it is, "nothing is perfect, not even the wheel that everyone elses uses... you have an idea that wants to grow. ask someone who can help make that happen."

- MC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calling system objects from an array of indexed + joined strings

If you have **.NET type names stored in *strings***,

- **cast to `[type]` to convert them to *type objects***; in PSv5+ you can **call the static `::new()` method** on such such type objects in order to **create *instances*** of that type.

  - `$typeName = 'System.DateTime'; $type = [type] $typeName; $instance = $type::new(0)`
- **Alternatively (PSv4-), pass the type-name string to `New-Object` to create an instance**.

  - `$typeName = 'System.DateTime'; New-Object $typeName -Args 0`

Note: In both cases, you'll need to know the appropriate constructor arguments to pass, if any.

---

> Calling assemblies or assembly types from an array of strings

Your example suggests that you want to ***import namespaces* into your code**, so you can more conveniently refer to types by just their *name* (e.g., `[Encoding]`) rather than having to use the type's *full name* (e.g., `[System.Text.Encoding]`), which C# implements as `using <namespace>`.

PowerShell's equivalent feature is `using namespace <type-name>`, but it only works with *literal* type names (as in C#).

Also, unlike with type literals such as `[Text.Encoding]`, omitting the `System` component is *not* optional, so `using namespace System.Text` works, but `using namespace Text` doesn't (it is quietly accepted, but ineffective).

You can work around that by using `Invoke-Expression` (whose use [should otherwise be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)):

```
$namespace = 'System.Collections'

Invoke-Expression "using namespace $namespace"

# Now you can access the types in namespace System.Collections by
# their mere name.
[ArrayList]  # short for: [System.Collections.ArrayList]
```

---

> Example of redundant similar Function calls ... The idea to make it less redundant

It looks like you're trying to **define functions *dynamically***.

Because PowerShell functions are exposed as a PowerShell *drive* named `Function:`, you can use `Set-Content` to define functions dynamically:

```
$f = "Console" , "Warning" , "Success" , "Error"
$m = "White" , "Yellow" , "Green" , "Red"

0..($f.Count-1) | ForEach-Object {

    if ( $_ -eq 0 ) {  
      Function Log { param($MSG) $MSG | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force }
    }
    else {
      $funcName = $f[$_]
      Set-Content Function:$funcName @"
        param(`$MSG)
        Write-Host `$MSG -ForegroundColor $($m[$_])
        Log `$MSG
"@
    }

}
```

This will define function `Log` and wrapper functions `Warning`, `Success` and `Error`, which precede the call to `Log` with colored console output.

Note the use of an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) to define the function body as a multi-line string (for readability), and how embedded `$` chars. that shouldn't be expanded up front must be escaped as `` `$ ``.

Comment: ( $w , $s , $p ) = ( $r = "Principal" ) , "Identity" , "BuiltInRole" | % { [ Type ] "Security.$r.Windows$_" }

$r = ( New-Object $w $s::GetCurrent() ).IsInRole( $p::( $a = "Administrator" ) )

| I have a more elaborate version of this that handles things a bit more specifically , but I've been at trying to make ^ work differently. Maybe it seems trivial... but I feel as if the work to find an alternate method has paid off.
| Thanks again mklement0

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @MichaelC.CookSr. Note that in PSv5+ the `using namespace` statement also allows for more concise commands: `using namespace System.Security.Principal; ([WindowsPrincipal] [WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole('Administrators')`

Comment: interesting... is it fair to say that 'using namespace' is the same thing as, or otherwise similar to 'New-Object' ?

Comment: No, @MichaelC.CookSr., it's the equivalent of `using` in C#; that is, it "imports" a namespace so that you can refer to its types by name only. However, my example uses a _cast_ (to `[WindowsPrincipal] `), as a faster and more concise alternative to `New-Object` or `<type>::Parse()`.

Comment: I see. Each of those types have a lot of options, wasn't sure what they were doing in conjunction... Still your idea is pretty cool. Working on a way to do some ASP.Net magic with it.